# Ошибка при выполнении команды Insert на C#

Tags: c#, access

Имеется следующий код для вставки записи в базу Access:

```
OleDbConnection conn = OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:/BD.mdb");

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ThemeTest (Id_theme, NameTheme, NumberQuestion, Prim) VALUES " + "(@Id_theme , @NameTheme, @NumberQuestion, @Prim);";
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_theme", 5);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameTheme", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberQuestion", numericUpDown1.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prim", textBox2.Text);
conn.Open();
// cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Здесь выдает ошибку о неверной команде Insert 
conn.Close();
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ThemeTest (Id_theme, NameTheme, NumberQuestion, Prim) VALUES " + "(@Id_theme , @NameTheme, @NumberQuestion, @Prim);";
```

Пропустили into в команде инсерта.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into ThemeTest (Id_theme, NameTheme, NumberQuestion, Prim) VALUES " + "(@Id_theme , @NameTheme, @NumberQuestion, @Prim);";
```

Comment: точно). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для генерации тривиальных команд желательно использовать класс `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder`